# Return data from a web scraper, async issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am stuck in a bit of a javascript callback issue. I have used a node library to scrape data from a client website before with success https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis. Now I need it to scrape and return within another loop. I will dumb down the code a bit, but its something like this.

```
// within a loop of another parsing library (simplified)
 .on("data", function(obj){
   listing = { 
    listing['img'] = scrape(obj['ID']); 
   }
   priceArray.push(listing);
 })
 .on("end", function(){
    // use this data
 })

 // osmosis scrape function to be used inside loop
 // just need it to return value so it can be pushed into array above
 function scrape(id){

   osmosis
    .get('http://www.xxxxxx.com/searchnew.aspx?sv=~'+ id)
    .find('.productImg > a')
    .set('img', '@img')
    .data(function(listing) {
      newImg = listing;
    })
    .done(function() {
      return newImg;
     });

 }
```

Now I know this is a function of callback and that returning within the done parameter isn't the right way. but if I set a variable within the scrape function and return it at the bottom its blank bc its processed before the osmosis command is run. Just killing me stacking callbacks within loops. Please help

Comment: You want `function scrape` to return the value you're returning in the `.done` callback therein?  This isn't possible because `scrape` will return `undefined` before this callback is ever invoked.  Instead, you need to use an async approach.  You can only assign the value to `listing['img']` directly using es7 `await`, but you can use `Promise`s or callbacks to do the same now.  Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: if the problem is that you're creating callback hell, then, yes, Promises can help you there